# Get the value of the billing street input field in Magento via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am trying to get the value of the billing street address input fields in Magento 1.7 - I have tried various things such as but none seem to work..

Any ideas??

```
<input type="text" class="input-text  required-entry" value="1 High Street" id="billing:street1" name="billing[street][]" title="Street Address">
```

My js

```
jQuery('#billing:street1').val();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the special character in selector.

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

```
jQuery('#billing\\:street1').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5NW9/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try `$$('[name="billing:street1"]').value`